# How would I make this CASE statement in the WHERE clause into a multi select parameter?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I need to be able to select all 3 of them when I make this into a report. I know its a little silly with the 3rd option but the client wants to be able to click all 3.

```
AND CASE WHEN @Display IN (1) AND (POPGT.LimitedQty >= 1 OR POPDX.LimitedQty >= 1) THEN 1
     WHEN @Display IN (2) AND (POPGT.NewSingleOrderQty >= 1 OR POPDX.NewSingleOrderQty >= 1) THEN 1
     WHEN @Display IN (0) THEN 1 END = 1
```

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `case` expression.  Something like this:

```
(@Display IN ('1', '*') AND (POPGT.LimitedQty >= 1 OR POPDX.LimitedQty >= 1)) OR
(@Display IN ('2', '*') AND (POPGT.NewSingleOrderQty >= 1 OR POPDX.NewSingleOrderQty >= 1)) OR
(@Display IN ('0', '*'))
```

Comment: I got it to work the way I wanted it to by switching it around a little

('1' IN (@Display) AND (POPGT.LimitedQty >= 1 OR POPDX.LimitedQty >= 1)) OR
('2' IN (@Display) AND (POPGT.NewSingleOrderQty >= 1 OR POPDX.NewSingleOrderQty >= 1)) OR
('0' IN (@Display))